# How can you set an actionlistener on the ok option of a jdialog?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jdialog

Hi i want to trigger some action when the ok button of jdialog is pressed, i know that you can do this way

```
int rep =JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, pangesfac, "Gestion des chambres a facturer", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    if(rep == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {//actions to do}
```

but in my case i want an external controller to take care of the things that have to be done (my code is structured by mvc) when the ok button is pressed. SO how can you set set up an action listner on the ok button ?

Answer (score 5):

It is possible but it isn't as easy as adding an ActionListener to the OK button. You have to use a PropertyChangeListener.

An example is shown on this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#stayup

However you might want to reconsider your design. You can still pass the result from the JOptionPane to your controller without capturing the event itself.

Comment: And is it possible to make another button in the jdialog other than the ok and cancel one to do the actions and then close the jdialog ?

Comment: you should use JOptionPane#showOptionDialog for that. You can provide a String[] array to set the option captions. There is an example on the page i posted earlier or check the API http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog

Comment: @user2133558: or use a custom made modal (if desired) JDialog, not a JOptionPane. 1+ to Ozzie for the answer.